# PDF Export using Rotativa in Azure Cloud Service - Issues with non Latin Character Sets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, azure-cloud-services, rotativa

I have an Azure Cloud Service with a Web role (ASP.NET MVC Web App) that allows downloading PDFs. The site supports many different languages across the globe. We are using Rotativa for PDF generation. It works perfectly fine for English, French, Español and many other Latin based character sets.

But even though the website displays Chinese and Japanese character sets properly, the downloaded PDFs don't. They show up as a series of empty blocks in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Found that Rotativa by default doesn't support non UTF8 characters. I am trying to use a different PDF Generator.